How to avoid password request in Linux after reboot?
I have scheduled a reboot in crontab and I want to avoid to insert password when Linux starts after reboot, but only in this case. In all other cases, I want the password active for safety reasons.
I have tried in sudo visudo, with this line:
user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown

But with no success... After rebooting Linux asks me the for the password.
Can you instruct me how to proceed?

Are you asking about logging back in after rebooting without a password? if so, that's outside the control of the command used to initiate the reboot afaik

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

I Have solved. Thanks to all

I don't think there is a command for that. You can just enable Automatic Login and then disable it after rebooting through Ubuntu's Settings.
To enable Automatic Login:

Go to Settings → System → Users.

Click Unlock... on the top right. You will be asked for your user's password.


After entering your password, enable Automatic Login:



After rebooting, just repeat the above procedure to disable Automatic Login.
